# Weird crest in first wavelength when summing bandpass filter outputs

Tags: audio, filtering, audio-processing, puredata, bandpass-filter

I am creating sounds by exciting bandpass filters with a short impulse and summing the outputs together. The more filters I use the more there seems to be a clipping sound at the very beginning. When I visualize the sound wave I realize the gain of the first crest of the first wavelength is higher than it shoud be when compared to the next wavelenght. When I just have one filter the output is fine. I attach the patch and the sound wave with one filter and with four filters for illustration. How can I correct that first crest? Has it got anything to do with the phase? Cheers[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4A18.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer on another forum. It is a phase problem. I solved it by changing the phase of every other bandpass filter by multiplying the output by `[*~ -1]`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: multiplying by *1* (`[*~ 1]`) won't change anything (hopefully). did you perchance meant *-1*? (and please accept your own answer, so the question is properly marked as *resolved*)

Comment: Yes I forgot the most important element in the answer, the minus! Cheers!